# How can I generate a colormap array from a simple array in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

In some functions of `matplotlib`, we have to pass an `color` argument instead of a `cmap` argument, like `bar3d`.

So we have to generate a `Colormap` manually. If I have a `dz` array like this:

```
dz = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

What I want is:

```
ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, color=cm.jet(dz), zsort='average')
```

However, It does not work, it seems `Colormap` instances can only convert normalized arrays.

```
>>> dz = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> cm.jet(dz)
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.51782531,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.53565062,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.55347594,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.57130125,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.58912656,  1.        ]])
```

Of course, this is not what I want.

I have to do things like this:

```
>>> cm.jet(plt.Normalize(min(dz),max(dz))(dz))
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.5       ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.50392157,  1.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.49019608,  1.        ,  0.47754586,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  0.58169935,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.5       ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ]])
```

How ugly the code is!

In [matplotlib's document](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap) it is said:

> Typically Colormap instances are used to convert data values (floats)
>   from the interval [0, 1] to the RGBA color that the respective
>   Colormap represents. For scaling of data into the [0, 1] interval see
>   matplotlib.colors.Normalize. It is worth noting that
>   matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable subclasses make heavy use of this
>   data->normalize->map-to-color processing chain.

So why I can't use just `cm.jet(dz)`?

Here are the imports that I am using

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The answer to your question is given in the snipplet of the documentation that you copied into your question:

> ...from the interval [0, 1] to the RGBA color...

But if you find your code *ugly* you could try to make it nicer:

1. You don't have to specify the limits to the normalization manually (iff you intent to use min/max):

   ```
   norm = plt.Normalize()
   colors = plt.cm.jet(norm(dz))
   ```
2. If you find that ugly (I don't understand why, though), you could go on and do it manually):

   ```
   colors = plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0,1,len(dz)))
   ```

   However this is solution is limited to equally spaced colors (which is what you want given the `dz` in your example.
3. And then you can also replicate the functionality of `Normalize` (since you seem to not like it):

   ```
   lower = dz.min()
   upper = dz.max()
   colors = plt.cm.jet((dz-lower)/(upper-lower))
   ```
4. Use a helper function:

   ```
   def get_colors(inp, colormap, vmin=None, vmax=None):
       norm = plt.Normalize(vmin, vmax)
       return colormap(norm(inp))
   ```

   Now you can use it like this:

   ```
   colors = get_colors(dz, plt.cm.jet)
   ```

Comment: How do you plot a colorbar for this?