# How does a LinearSegmentedColorMap convert integer values into colors?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider this example

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter([1,2,3], [1,2,3], c=[0,1,2], cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap("brg"), s=100)
```

[image]

How can I see the RGBA values selected by this color map? Note that [the docs state](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html#linearsegmentedcolormap)

> LinearSegmentedColormaps do not have a .colors attribute. However, one may still call the colormap with an integer array, or with a float array between 0 and 1.

However, when I attempt this, it does not appear to work.

```py
import numpy as np

cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap("brg")
cmap(np.array([0,1,2], dtype='int64'))
array([[0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 1.        ],
       [0.00784314, 0.        , 0.99215686, 1.        ],
       [0.01568627, 0.        , 0.98431373, 1.        ]])
```

These RGBA values don't align with what I expect (blue, red, green).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I generate a colormap array from a simple array in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28144142/how-can-i-generate-a-colormap-array-from-a-simple-array-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Matplotlib uses a ["norm"](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html) to convert the `c=` values from their current range to `0...1`.  By default, the lowest of the values in `c=` will be converted to `0` for the "lowest" color (blue in this case) and the highest value of `c=` will be converted to `1` to represent the "highest" color. The rest will go linearly in between.  If you just call `cmap(...)` using an array, when the array is of float type, they are interpreted to from 0 (lowest) to 1 (highest). If, however, you use integers, they go from 0 to 255.

Comment: You could use `cmap(np.linspace(0,1,256))`, or `cmap(np.arange(0, 256))` to obtain the full list of colors. Note that matplotlib precalculates these 256 colors for this "LinearSegmentedColormap".

Comment: Thank you both. Quite helpful - I searched but couldn't find this.